# scrape data from into dataframe with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I'm working on a project to scrape and parse data from California lottery into a `dataframe`

Here's my code so far, it produces no error **but** also no output:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs4

draw = 'http://www.calottery.com/play/draw-games/superlotto-plus/winning-numbers/?page=1'
page = requests.get(draw) 
soup = bs4(page.text)

drawing_list = []

for table_row in soup.select("table.tag_even_numbers tr"):
    cells = table_row.findAll('td')

    if len(cells) > 0:
        draw_date = cells[0].text.strip()
        numbers = cells[1].text.strip()
        mega = cells[2].text.strip()

        drawings = {'dates': draw_date, 'winning_numbers': numbers, 'mega_number': mega}
        drawing_list.append(drawings)
        print "added {0} {1} {2}, to the list".format(draw_date, numbers, mega)
```

**Expected Output:** I'd love to scrape the table rows into a `dataframe`

```
draw_date  | numbers        | mega
-----------|----------------|-----
12/06/2017 | 12 24 07 01 02 | 23
12/02/2017 | 33 18 07 42 40 | 7
```

Thanks for any revision or assistance into the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This expression `"table.tag_even_numbers tr"` selects nothing because the table has no 'tag_even_numbers' class, but has a 'tag_even' class and a 'numbers' class.

So if you change this:

```
soup.select("table.tag_even_numbers tr")
```

to:

```
soup.select("table.tag_even.numbers tr")
```

you should have 20 items in `drawing_list`.

Also by using `.text` to select `numbers` you get all the numbers joined side by side in a string.
If you want a list of numbers you should use `.stripped_strings` instead, eg:

```
numbers = list(cells[1].stripped_strings)
```

Then you can create a dataframe from `drawing_list`, eg:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(drawing_list)
print(df.head())
```

---

```
                 dates mega_number       winning_numbers
0   Dec 6, 2017 - 3201          23  [12, 24, 07, 01, 02]
1   Dec 2, 2017 - 3200           7  [33, 18, 07, 42, 40]
2  Nov 29, 2017 - 3199           6  [03, 33, 26, 27, 07]
3  Nov 25, 2017 - 3198          19  [21, 46, 13, 25, 17]
4  Nov 22, 2017 - 3197           3  [32, 40, 27, 42, 08]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. and the suggestion of `stripped_strings` it saves me an extra step of splitting the string. super helpful.
any suggestions for pushing into a dataframe?